# Need database structure for private, group and public chat - MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

My basic idea is to build a web-based chat application. I have checked a lot of database structures over the internet for my requirements and the conclusion is that there are so many solutions for that.

So here is the database structure I thought (But I'm pretty sure that it is not 100% correct or at least it can be improved)

---

**Table users:**

id | username | email | created_at | updated_at

**Table chat_rooms**

id | room_type | created_at | updated_at

**Table: room_members**

id | room_id | user_ids (in serialized form)

**Table: messages**

id | room_id | sender_id | message | created_at | updated_at

**Table: receivers**

id | message_id | receiver_id | read_at

---

**There are 3 types of chats:**

i) Private chat - a chat between two users

- A user will select another user to start to chat with him/her

ii) Group chat - a chat between group of users

- A user will add other users into the room to start a group chat

iii) Public chat - a chat between all the users

- An open chat room to which anyone can join and send messages

**So here is how it will work:**

I logged into the site, redirected to the dashboard page. On that page, I have 3 options to start a chat as described above.

**Notes:**

1) If there is a previous chat between the users it should be shown as soon as I start a chat (pretty similar to Facebook) - This applies to all the three types of chats

2) I want to have a feature which says that when a specific user read a message.

3) I want to keep it scalable as much as possible for the future enhancement

Thanks

Comment: I think room_members and receivers don't need their own unique id, it can be just a composite key

Comment: A private chat and a group chat are really the same thing. It's about who has permission to add other people to the conversation

Comment: Maybe the table room_members should be id | room_id | user_id (1 record per room-user pair).

Answer (score -4):

Yes this DB structure is workable for make alpha version.
you can make some small changes according to your requirement.